# Is there a height limit for building?

Tags: starforge

I was wondering. In the new game StarForge Alpha (Version 0.4.6 and beyond), is there a height limit? For example, can you not build after going 500 blocks up? Or can you build forever?

Answer (score -2):

I suppose you can build on forever.
Sources: I built stairs a little over 2 km high which took me more than a day. I was trying to go to space.